# Email from a specific application not sending text in email body

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, app

Okay, so this will sound weird, and I will try to word it the best I can.

I have an app that I use for work (CCC One). Within the app, I can choose to send our customers an email with any selected attachments. When I choose this option, it opens up MS Outlook and a draft of an email with the sender and recipient's email address and the attachment, however, there is no text in the body (which is normal as this is where I modify the text). When I apply text and send the email, the recipient receives the attachment, but not the text.

However, If I were to save the attachment from the application, open a fresh email straight from Outlook, attach the document, add text to the body of the email, and send it, it works just fine.

Any advice on how to troubleshoot this?

Not sure if this is the right place to ask this but it looked like the most appropriate. If there is a better place to ask, let me know and I'll post it there.

Comment: Thought about approaching the developer?

Comment: I did. They pointed me at Microsoft, Microsoft then pointed the finger back at CCC. Really have no idea what could be going on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, If I were to save the attachment from the application, open a
> fresh email straight from Outlook, attach the document, add text to
> the body of the email, and send it, it works just fine.

Considering that you can send email with attachment directly in Outlook, i'm afraid that the issue is more related to CCC App.

If you are still unsure, it is recommended that you replace the default mail program with another software (such as Mail) to check if the problem persists. If another mail program has the same problem as Outlook, then undoubtedly that the problem is definitely with CCC.

Comment: That is a great idea. I will do that today. Thank you!

Comment: Hope to help you!  If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer.

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If it is useful, would you mind marking the helpful post as an answer? Which would benefit others who also has similar issues in forum.